# Implementing Inverse Mapping Texture Approach in OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, opengl, texture-mapping

I have to implement simple texturing in OpenGL using the inverse(or backwards) mapping approach. In theory, I know what it is and how it works, but I can't figure out how to implement it in OpenGL. Is there a way to specify how OpenGL handles textures in this regard?

I know, more or less, how to texture polygons, but this little side-note on the homework assignment is what bugs me:

> Note: The texture mapping is implemented using the inverse mapping
>   approach (do not use OpenGL texture mapping function)

Does anyone have any idea what is meant by this? I'm drawing the polygon to be textured with glBegin and glEnd and using glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) and glTexCoord2f to texture it. Is there another way of doing it, or am I reading too much into the assignment?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, which came with OpenGL installed, and have an AMD Radeon HD 6850 graphics card. This is for a simple homework assignment, so the simplest solution will suffice.

To save time, yes, this is for a homework, no, I don't want anyone to do it for me, just an indication as to how I would go about doing it myself, and no, an extensive google search gave me no insight whatsoever as to how this would be implemented in code.

Comment: Doesn't OpenGL already do that for you? You give OpenGL a mesh with texture coordinates, activate the texture you want and say 'draw that!' What exactly do you have to implement? Do you just want to know how to set things up?

Comment: And complementary to what maddin45 said: what OpenGL version are you targeting? That stuff will look significantly different on the old, deprecated fixed-function pipeline in comparision to the modern programmable pipeline.

Comment: @maddin45 I thought so too, but the assignment seems to suggest otherwise. I've edited the OP to reflect my problem.

Comment: I am still not sure how to interpret the assignment either. Maybe they want you to implement the glTexGen functionality in a shader, but that's a wild guess. If you have homework forum or something like that you should probably ask there. Or ask some other students in your course, they might have the same problem.

Comment: @maddin45 I'll look into glTexGen, but I doubt that's it if it has anything to do with shaders. Thanks.